# Retrieve Element Tag Value XML Using Bash

Tags: xml, bash, xmllint

Is there a way that I can retrieve the value of an element (or the tag) in XML through a bash script?

For example, if I had the below XML, I'd like to retrieve the element , so that when I run the command, it simply returns "tag1" rather than any content within any of the other tags. I know I can use `xmllint` if I wanted to retrieve the valueTag3 content for example, but that is not what I'd like to do.

```
<tag1>
    <tag2>
        <tag3>valueTag3</tag3>
    </tag2>
</tag1>
```

If the above is possible (whether using `xmllint` or not), is there a way that I can specify that I'd like to return a child tag of its parent tag? For example, what would be the command if I wanted to return "tag2" (which is a child of tag1 above)?

Comment: `tag2` doesn't follow `tag1`, `tag2` is `tag1`'s child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See XPath syntax:

```
xmllint -xpath 'name(/tag1/tag2/*)' xmlsource
```

Comment: I've run the above command and it returns "valueTag3". As mentioned above, I'd like to return the tag itself (tag3 for example) rather than the value within it.

Comment: Oh, then you need to use `name()` function of XPath like this: `xmllint -xpath 'name(/tag1/tag2/*)` (Fixed above)

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I also found a potential solution using xmlStarlet which returns the structure of the xml file: `xml sel -T -t -m '//*' \
-m 'ancestor-or-self::*' -v 'name()' -i 'not(position()=last())' -o . -b -b -n \
source.xml` which could be handy.